# Program macro in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA macro for my work but I didn't get it. Please help me to find the correct program. Requirement of program - I want to copy entire rows (more than 1 rows) as current date basis and current date available in column D (in more than 1 cells),  it's a daily basis activities so everyday date change.

Comment: Record yourself doing it, then use that code to learn what you need.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+record+and+run+a+macro+in+excel+)

Answer (score 1):

Amit you can do it easily by recording this procedure in Excel, then you can customize it through using Visual Basic Editor. For more information take a look at  http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html
I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Dear All, thanks for your reply, i have tried the process that you have mention in above communication but i didn't get solution please advise if you have proper code/macro for my problem also i would like to inform you that i am a new learner of vba.

Comment: Hi, i have already sussed to write vab program only last two step is left to complete my work, this is my vab program:-                              Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Workbooks.Open ("Ware house in  out (2016).xls")
Sheets("August-16").Range("A1:AB1").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open ("FOR MAIL-3-DAYS TRACKING SHEET-15-DEC-14 .xlsx")
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AB1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
Workbooks("Ware house in  out (2016).xls").Activate


End Sub